# "Run-time error '1004'" when printing PDF

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to print the active worksheet into a PDF file.

I get

> "Run-time error '1004'"

It does seem to create the file but can't save it. I know because a printing load window opens for a second.

```vb
Dim saveLocation As String

saveLocation = "C:\Users\Desktop\work_hours.pdf"

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
  Filename:=saveLocation
```

Comment: what other details does the error give you?  I'm also a little suspicious of that file path.  Usually, I'd expect something like C:\Users\<your username>\Desktop\work_hours.pdf

Answer (score 2):

### Export to PDF

- If the reason behind your error is an invalid `Desktop` path, as `user3479671` suspected (in the comments), then the following could be useful.
- Run only `ExportWorkHours`, the rest is being called.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ExportWorkHours()
' Needs 'SaveAsPDFinDesktop' and 'GetDesktopPath'.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' be more specific
    SaveAsPDFinDesktop ws, "work_hours.pdf"
End Sub

Sub SaveAsPDFinDesktop( _
        ByVal ws As Worksheet, _
        ByVal pdfFileName As String)
' Needs 'GetDesktopPath'.

    Dim DesktopPath As String: DesktopPath = GetDesktopPath
    If Len(DesktopPath) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Could not find the Desktop path.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=DesktopPath & pdfFileName
    ' Explore the file path
    'ws.Parent.FollowHyperlink DesktopPath

End Sub

Function GetDesktopPath() As String

    Dim DesktopPath As String
    DesktopPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\" & "Desktop\"

    Dim FolderName As String
    FolderName = Dir(DesktopPath, vbDirectory)

    If Len(FolderName) = 0 Then
        DesktopPath = Environ("OneDrive") & "\" & "Desktop\"
        FolderName = Dir(DesktopPath, vbDirectory)
    End If

    If Len(FolderName) = 0 Then Exit Function

    GetDesktopPath = DesktopPath

End Function
```